# React-redux @connect does not work, but connect() does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am unable to use the `@connect()` syntax in place of `export default connect()`

I've noticed that when I use the usual syntax

```
class PhonePage extends Component { ... }

export default connect(state => ({
        testedByPhone: state.phonepage.testedByPhone
    }),
    (dispatch) => ({
        actions: bindActionCreators(testUserPhone, dispatch)
    })
)(PhonePage)
```

I get my state properly registered in my store.

And it looks like this: `Object {screenProps: undefined, navigation: Object, testedByPhone: Object}`

But when I use the @connect decorator to make things cleaner, I don't get anything listed in my state.

```
@connect(
    state => ({
        testedByPhone: state.phonepage.testedByPhone
    }), 
    { testUserPhone }
)
class PhonePage extends Component { ... }

export default PhonePage
```

Suddenly it's somehow not actually connecting things: `Object {screenProps: undefined, navigation: Object}`

**What am I doing wrong, and what is the correct way to use the magical @connect decorator that I see everyone using?**

---

The rest of the code, just in case it's needed, in the form of @connect;

```js
'use strict'

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Button,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native'
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { testUserPhone } from './actions'

import PhoneInput from 'react-native-phone-input'

@connect(
    state => ({
        testedByPhone: state.phonepage.testedByPhone
    }), 
    { testUserPhone }
)
class PhonePage extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // this.props.testUserPhone
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return(
            ...
        )
    }
}

export default PhonePage

// export default connect(state => ({
//         testedByPhone: state.phonepage.testedByPhone
//     }),
//     (dispatch) => ({
//         actions: bindActionCreators(testUserPhone, dispatch)
//     })
// )(PhonePage)

// module.exports = PhonePage
```

Comment: Are you transforming decorators correctly? Can we see your build steps?

Comment: @ZekeDroid I don't actually know what you mean by that, 'transforming' them? Build steps? If you tell me how I can get that info for you I will.

Comment: @AndrewLi It seems like you don't need dispatch as a param according to this tutorial, that's the only reason http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNkTQtRUH-M&t=23m51s

Comment: @ZekeDroid Wait actually do you mean my babelrc file? All it has is { presets: ["react-native"], "plugins": ["syntax-decorators"]}

Comment: @AndrewLi I think that the decorator syntax already includes the dispatch by default, and by passing in your action it's automatically linked up - at least it is for the guy in the video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@connect` decorator, or decorators in general, are not native to JavaScript. However, you can add them in via Babel.

You can read more on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646920/whats-the-at-symbol-in-the-redux-connect-decorator)

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy
```

Comment: I added mine as a plugin to Babel - still doesn't help :(

Comment: @ARMATAV Which plugin did you use?

Comment: "syntax-decorators"

Comment: which one should i have?

Comment: @ARMATAV Try babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy

Comment: Deleted my old comment cause I messed up and installed it with 'uninstall --save-dev', YOU A GENIUS BREH - it worked!

Comment: @ARMATAV sorry I commented and forgot to check again! Yes that's what I was going to suggest based on your babelrc :) glad it worked out in the end

Answer (score 1):

For babel-6, follow @megaboy101's answer

For babel-7 use this

`{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
  ]
}`