# using higher order component in react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, higher-order-components

I'm reading an old project using react class component and they use `connect` from `react-redux` like this:

```js
@pageAntdLayout
@injectIntl    
@connect
class List extends Component {
    ....
}
```

Then I try to find the way using `connect` from `react-redux`, it's used like a Higher Order Component, e.g. `connect(Component)`.

So I really wonder is this the way to using HOC in class component?

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646920/whats-the-at-symbol-in-the-redux-connect-decorator

Comment: If you are looking for what does the syntax means, then it's called 'decorators'. Checkout these blogs: https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-javascript-decorators/ and https://medium.com/fraight/react-redux-decorators-8b38f3b9ef2f

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/happypoulp/redux-tutorial/issues/87